# What are degrees of freedom in this context?

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, vibrations, degrees-of-freedom

> For translational motion,
>   $$H_\text{trans} = \frac{p_x^2}{2m} + \frac{p_y^2}{2m} + \frac{p_z^2}{2m}$$
>   For rotational motion,
>   $$H_\text{rot} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{L_x^2}{I_x} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{L_y^2}{I_y}$$
>   neglecting motion about z-axis.
>   For vibrational motion,
>   $$H_\text{vib} = \frac{p_z'^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}k_0 z'^2$$
>   where $z'$ is the relative coordinate between two atoms.
>
> Therefore, the total internal energy $U$ should be $\frac{7}{2}N k T$. However the experimental results show that $U = \frac{5}{2} N k T$.

Here he states that the hamiltonian contains all these terms, but is there a difference between these terms and if i say:

$$H = \frac{p_{x_{1}}^{2}}{2m_{1}} + \frac{p_{y_{1}}^{2}}{2m_{1}} + \frac{p_{z_{1}}^{2}}{2m_{1}} + \frac{p_{x_{2}}^{2}}{2m_{2}} + \frac{p_{y_{2}}^{2}}{2m_{2}} + \frac{p_{z_{2}}^{2}}{2m_{2}} + \frac{kr^{2}}{2} \, .$$

My Hamiltonian here is the kinetic energies of the 2 masses and their interaction potential energy, which I'm used to writing it like that in classical mechanics.

How is it linked with his hamiltonian? I mean, isn't the rotational motion and vibrational motion already inside my kinetic energy expressions in general? Or am I doing something wrong?

Reference: https://www.academia.edu/38848245/Alfred_Huan_-_Statistical_Mechanics_0_    [Page 41]

Comment: Do you understand the difference between linear momentum and angular momentum?

Comment: I don't know enough of the situation you're looking at to say for sure, but this sort of thing is typically done when breaking things up into trans/rot/vib exposes underlying symmetries which make the calculations *much* easier going forward.

Comment: What I'm saying is, isn't my hamiltonian enough to describe the motion of the diatomic molecule? In his hamiltonian, he expresses the translational kinetic energy as  $H_\text{trans} = \frac{p_x^2}{2m} + \frac{p_y^2}{2m} + \frac{p_z^2}{2m}$ , What is that '$m$' in the denominator, which translational motion is he describing?

Comment: The degrees of freedom are determined by looking the motion about the center of mass for a diatomic molecule. Whether or not you count the vibrational degree of freedom depends on the temperature. At low temperature you ignore it - at high temperature you count it.